# Why does the electromagnetic repulsion between protons in the nuclei fail to prevent the formation of a black hole singularity?

Tags: black-holes, singularities

The process of forming a black hole requires all matter to be crushed into a point by gravitational attraction. But the electromagnetic repulsion between protons inside the nuclei of the atoms is way stronger than gravity. Then why does it fail to prevent the formation of the singularity?

Comment: And to add to the above comment, usually the theorized intermediate stages of black hole formation involve neutrons stars, so no need to really invoke proton proton repulsion.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly But for stars that can potentially form a BH, all atoms will eventually be crushed into a volume of subnuclear dimensions (I believe), and then there will be tremendous repulsion between protons. Is there anything wrong with this picture?

Comment: Blackhole is just a prediction of classical theory of gravity. At subatomic scale we might expect something else..

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Oh yes, thanks, my bad! However, I think the real answer lies in Triatticus's comment. Before a BH forms, there is the stage of neutron star formation which is almost entirely made of neutrons (protons and electrons combine to form neutrons), and no electrical repulsion remains to prevent the singularity. Thanks, all.

Comment: @KP99 I think you mean that though BHs (event horizons, photon sphere, etc) can still exist in a quantum theory of gravity, but singularity will not.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 You're welcome. I deleted my comments because Triatticus's comment seems sufficient.

Comment: I don't know ... I shouldn't comment about what should and shouldn't exist without a prior knowledge of QG. What, I know is that all calculation for neutron star, Chandrashekhar limit etc etc involves Einstein's equation in semi classical limit.